# Ruby - constants of same class type

Tags: ruby, enums

I tried the following but got an error 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)':

```
class Rating
  NOOB = Rating.new(1, "U A NOOB")
  def initialize(rating, message)
    @rating = rating
    @message = message
  end
 end
```

What would be the equivalent of writing the following in Ruby? (this is my way of doing enums)

```
public class Rating {
  public static Rating NOOB = new Rating(1, "U SO NOOB");
  public static Rating EXPERT = new Rating(2, "U A PRO BRO");

  private int rating;
  private String message;

  public Rating(int rating, String message) {
    this.rating = rating;
    this.message = message;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you put

```
NOOB = Rating.new(1, "U A NOOB")
```

below the definition of `initialize`, as otherwise the interpreter hasn't interpreted it, yet, and doesn't know about the arguments it takes.

Comment: It's not that the interpreter doesn't know about the arguments it takes. It is rather that the default `initialize` is called, which takes zero arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you put the constant declaration at the end of the initialize block it works:

```
class Rating
  def initialize(rating, message)
    @rating = rating
    @message = message
  end
  NOOB = new(1, "U A NOOB")
end

p Rating::NOOB
=> #<Rating:0x0000000162a9c0 @rating=1, @message="U A NOOB">
```